# Как проинициализировать переменную в data позже с vue3 typescript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript, nuxt.js, typescript-типы

```
<script lang="ts">

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      timer: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    screensaver(ev) {
      console.log("up" + config.TIMEOUT)
      if (this.timer) window.clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.$router.push('/logout')
      },  120);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', this.screensaver)
  },
```

Как сделать чтоб this.timer не подчеркивало `Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'null'.`

Пробовал

```
  data() {
    let timer : ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null= null
    return {
      timer
    }
  }
```

Comment: Очевидно, что не использовать TS на options api, так как тут это нормально сделать и не выйдет (именно поэтому появился composition api, потому что появилась потребность использовать TS). В composition api можно было бы определить типы как `const timer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null = ref(null)`

Comment: Комплзишн за пределами сетап () работать будет нормально?

Comment: Может просто подавить этот тип `this.timer = setTimeout(...) as any`

Comment: @eri А что вы за пределами setup с vue собрались делать? Там уже чистый JS/TS идёт, в основном.